# If $f$ is periodic and has derivative that is sectionally continuous then $\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty} n\hat{f}(n)=0$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $f$ is periodic and has derivative that is sectionally continuous(piecewise continuous) then $\lim_{|n|\rightarrow\infty} n\hat{f}(n)=0$

Just need someone to explain to me in layman's terms why I need the stated hypothesis for the problem. I'm confused as to why we need periodicity of $2\pi$ and a sectionally continuous derivative if we are just showing fourier coefficients converge to zero, will I need the fact that it will be bounded above to show convergence to $0$? I'm assuming the reason that $|n|\rightarrow\infty$ is to say that there is no fourier transform representation, am I understanding the preface for developing a proof? If you dislike my question please justify, no proof does not imply bad question

Update with proof attempt:
$2\pi\hat{f}(n)=\int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta=\frac{1}{in}\int_0^{2\pi}f'(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta$, where we obtained the second equality by integration by parts and where the first term of the integration, which I did not post, goes to zero since we have periodicity. So $2\pi|n||\hat{f}(n)|\leq|\int_0^{2\pi}f'(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta|\leq\int_0^{2\pi}|f'(\theta)|d\theta\leq C$ where  C is independent of $n$ and we are done.

Comment: Notice you're not just proving that the Fourier coefficients tend to zero (which is true for any integrable $f$), but that they do so faster than $1/n$.

Comment: hmm, great point to bring up. That's very interesting

Comment: I figured it out, it's a very simple proof. Similar example helped. I'll edit my comments

Comment: Can't I just say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{1}{in}\int_0^{2\pi}f'(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta|=0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? It's integrable since it has a Fourier series representation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant that $f$ is $2\pi$-periodic and  the primitive of a piecewise continuous $2\pi$-periodic function, denoted $f'$.

You only proved that $|n \hat{f}(n)|$ is bounded, not that it $\to 0$.

For this, show that as $n\to \infty$
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} |f'(x)-f'(x+\pi/n)|dx\to 0$$
Then use
$$2 \widehat{f'}(n)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} (f'(x)-f'(x+\pi/n)) e^{-inx}dx$$

Comment: Is that product of $2$ and $\hat{f}(n)$ meant to be there?

Comment: That $2$ seems out of place, anyway I'm working out the info you gave me into my proof to see how it's going to work. Thank you!

Comment: Ah yes sorry I corrected

Comment: Can't I just say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{1}{in}\int_0^{2\pi}f'(\theta)e^{-in\theta}d\theta|=0$ by the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma? It's integrable since it has a Fourier series representation. But I'm not too sure how to prove the Lemma, I'm not familiar with it yet, so don't know if I can use it

Comment: Why do we need the fourier coefficients of the derivative? I'm intrigued into your method of arguing this case, seems like the natural way to go about it using given hypothesis

Comment: I'll keep thinking on it

Comment: Why do I have the feeling that it should be $n\hat{f}(n)$ and not $\hat{2f'(n)}$? You yanking my tail here?

Comment: Sure $\widehat{f'}(n)= in \hat{f}(n)$.   I am the proving Riemann Lebesgue lemma (for piecewise continuous functions, though the idea is similar for $L^1[0,2\pi]$ functions). @user5896534